# Shortcut alt+enter is not working in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

<kbd>alt</kbd> +  <kbd>enter</kbd>for importing was work normally maybe until I updated Android Studio,
my version now is`2.3.3`

as this screenshot, I can't press <kbd>alt</kbd> +  <kbd>enter</kbd> at all, knowing that I have tested them on other programs and they are working normally
[image]

Comment: Restarting Android Studio worked for me.

Comment: @40-Love, I have reinstalled windows and android studio for other reasons and I was fixed then

Answer (score 17):

Use `LEFT Alt Key + Enter`. It works well in Android Studio 3.0.1.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem today, this is how I solved it.

1. Go to `File  > Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import`
2. Uncheck and Check `Show Import Popup`
3. Do `Invalidate caches and Restart` of Android Studio. (If this option doesn't work, restart your computer

**Edit**
Another solution I've found to work is to uninstall Android Studio and reinstall it.

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately, I have tried that, but it seems to be a bug cuz when u reinstalled my windows (not for android studio) it works again

Comment: @DasserBasyouni what did you do to fix it? I have the same issue(

Comment: @MarinaGazibar I have reinstalled my windows for other reasons, and updated my android studio to 3.0 (just for updating it, I wasn't trying to fix that) and that bug is gone, I think it might be a bug with the settings saved data of the Android Studio

Comment: @DasserBasyouni thank you for answer. I just reinstalled AndroidStudio and it did not helped. And it makes me crazy. Reinstalling Windows was not in my plans)

Comment: @MarinaGazibar you're welcome, also happy to see you fixed it, that keyboard driver wasn't even in my problem cases, I think if it happens again I will check it

Comment: Thanks "Invalidate caches and Restart" worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Try "the Windows Key + Alt + Enter" if you are using windows.

It feels weird as I am pretty sure my keyboard works fine and android studio settings are alright, but I just see the pop-up suggestion for class import and nothing happens when I press Alt+Enter.

I work on Windows 10 and my Android SDK is on a different hard drive(E:) from the Android Studio installation(C:), not sure if these contribute to the problem.

After some trial and error I accidentally solved the problem by pressing "the Windows Key + Alt + Enter" to conjure the import class menu and could then press Enter again to properly import the suggested class.

Comment: That's bizarre, indeed. Now, I am always compelled to use Win+Alt+Enter, as you described. Thank you for the solution, though.

Answer (score 4):

1. In the Android studio Settings/Keymap  "shortcut Ctrl+Alt+S"

> search for usage of "Alt + Ent" as below image if its not assigned for any action plz go for No. 2

[image: Android studio shortcut]

---

2. In the Android studio Settings/Editor/Intentions.

> Check whatever you want to show Intention in are checked or not as below photo

[image: Intention]

---

3. Double check no.1 is working fine and you found usage of "Alt + Ent" shortcut

---

[You can find the solution on official Jet brains website]

[Intellij IDEA keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

[Intention actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html)

Comment: Thank you, "Show Intention Actions" was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and was sure that the problem is in Android Studio. But when I reinstalled it I realized that it did not helped. So I decided to test my keyboard. I found that my left Alt is not working with Enter and right Alt somewhy is turning on Ctrl key. That is why Alt+Enter was not working in any combinations. Problem was solved by reinstalling keyboard driver. Hope it will helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For Windows/Linux, you can go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Auto Import` -> `Java` and make the following changes:

- change `Insert imports on paste` value to `All` if `ask` or `none` to `All`
- mark`Add unambigious imports on the fly` option as checked

On a Mac, do the same thing in `Android Studio` -> `Preferences`

Comment: already have done that and it still the same, also the only difference between my AS and urs is that I have empty exclude from import and completion & I have a tick on show import suggestions for static methods and fields (that's isn't available in ur AS)

Answer (score 1):

Go to File and Unchecked Power Save mode.

Comment: Nay, didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If someone encounters this issue nowadays, for me it was the language change on the keyboard. I must have made some weird keyboard combination that changed the language, therefore ALT + ENTER was not really doing I was thinking it should do. Switching it back to ENG made it work correctly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

in Android Studio 3.2.1, the Alt + Enter combination key is only used on the left side of the keyboard.

If you want to use the Alt to the right, it should be manually selected from the section

Settings> Keymap> other

Right-click on the row

show intention action

select add keyboard shortcut
Press **Alt (Right)** + Enter

I hope this helps

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: in android studio 3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

it was the problem with the latest version to...instead of pressing alt+enter. use ctr+o it will open a dialog box then select the method u want to implement and then click on ok button ..its works with all version of android studio.. { Happy coding ;) }

Comment: Not really answering the question, but the Ctrl+O shortcut is useful. Thanks for that.

Comment: ctrl + o is supposed to open a list of methods for a class you can override

Answer (score 1):

In my case (v4.0.0) there was a plugin (CSV Plugin) blocking the shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd> +  <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Generally speaking, my suggestion is to try deactivating all the plugins and see if then it works.

Comment: You are a genius! I was going crazy trying to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the same issue and none of the above fixed the problem. I thought I  was using Alt+Enter for Parameter info. Now I use Ctrl+p I get the parameter info for the widget. Not sure if this was changed from Alt+Enter to Ctrl+p but if looking in the  File/Setting/Keymap it shows Ctrl+P.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and what worked is Alt+Insert combination

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to check is did you put the code inside the onCreate function?
If not put it there and try again. the Alt+ Enter would work after that.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue after I upgraded Ubuntu. Left Alt+Enter was working but more comfortable Right Alt+Enter did't. Resolved using [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1133154) in AskUbuntu.

In case if you cannot open the link:

> Open "Tweaks" (aka "Gnome Tweaks") go to "Keyboard & Mouse" -> "Additional Layout Options" -> "Key to choose the 3rd level" and put a check mark on "Right Alt never chooses 3rd level".

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Then I found that I was typing the 
`public void functionName (View view)` outside the class. Hence <kbd>alt</kbd> +  <kbd>enter</kbd> did not work.

After I moved the function inside the class, <kbd>alt</kbd> +  <kbd>enter</kbd> worked.

This is a silly mistake though.

Answer (score 0):

I just pressed alt + f4 to exit and pressed cancel just to check if alt key was working. Fortunately after that everything was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  1)setting > 2)intensions > 3)checkmark (Dart) and it will work normally without any problem.