# Basic question : Alt + Enter shortcut not working for me

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm starting Learning Flutter 2.0,

with a basic set up (Windows 10 + Android Studio ).

And i understood that thanks to the magical shortcut "Alt+enter" it should make my life easier .

To convert a Stateless widget to Stateful, or to Wrap with Column, or Extract Widget, ...

But It's not working for me.

Whad did i miss ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53723374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you installed the latest version of flutter and dart [plugins](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor).

And if you already did please restart the IDE. Use `left Alt+enter` to check.

`Invalidate caches and Restart` might help.

Comment: Android studio restart Worked. I was too lazy to check. Thank you